# xarray groupby.map( ) not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, python-xarray

I have xarray dataset(monthly_data) with following info:

```
data.tas

Output:
xarray.Datarray 'tas': (time:14400 lat: 192 lon: 288)
array([[[45,46,45,4....],....]...]

Coordinates:
lat:
array([-90. , -89.75,...])

lon:
array([0., 1.25.,.... ])

time:
array([cftime.DatetimeNoLeap(0001-01-15 12:00:00),
       cftime.DatetimeNoLeap(0001-02-15 12:00:00),
       cftime.DatetimeNoLeap(0001-03-15 12:00:00), ...,
       cftime.DatetimeNoLeap(1199-01-15 12:00:00),
       cftime.DatetimeNoLeap(1199-02-15 12:00:00),
       cftime.DatetimeNoLeap(1199-03-15 12:00:00)]
```

Now I want to calculate monthly_anomaly which I can directly calculate by following code:

```
data.groupby('time.month') - data.groupby('time.month').mean()
```

And I'm getting the correct output:

```
array([[[-23.27832 , -23.27832 , -23.27832 , ..., -23.27832 , -23.27832 ,
        -23.27832 ],
       [-27.643555, -27.590332, -27.537598, ..., -27.812012, -27.751953,
        -27.689453],
       [-30.249512, -30.344727, -30.437988, ..., -29.96045 , -30.054688,
        -30.155762]],
       ...,
      [[ 64.62012 ,  64.71045 ,  64.796875, ...,  64.36719 ,  64.45361 ,
         64.53662 ],
       [ 68.956055,  69.02734 ,  69.08789 , ...,  68.78467 ,  68.836914,
         68.896484],
       [ 72.59424 ,  72.59424 ,  72.59375 , ...,  72.59375 ,  72.59375 ,
         72.59375 ]]], dtype=float32)
```

But there's other way to do so using map which I read on:
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/groupby.html

Section: **Apply**

Where the same thing I can do by:

```
def standardize(x):
  return (x - x.mean())

new_monthly_anomalies = data.groupby('time.month').map(standardize)
```

But I don't  know what i'm doing wrong it's not giving me correct results. Can someone tell me why both are working differently?

Output of new_monthly_anomalies :

```
array([[[-410.8833 , -410.8833 , -410.8833 , ..., -410.8833 , -410.8833 ,
        -410.8833 ],
       [-415.70166, -415.62207, -415.5244 , ..., -415.94434, -415.86426,
        -415.7788 ],
       [-416.67676, -416.79053, -416.91162, ..., -416.35742, -416.46045,
        -416.5664 ],
       ...,
       [[-364.6006 , -364.4541 , -364.30713, ..., -365.03516, -364.8911 ,
        -364.7456 ],
       [-359.6787 , -359.6128 , -359.54346, ..., -359.85596, -359.8003 ,
        -359.74072],
       [-354.48242, -354.48242, -354.48242, ..., -354.48242, -354.48242,
        -354.48242]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Could you add a snippet showing what `new_monthly_anomalies` and the 'correct' version give you?

Comment: @AWilliams3142 please check the updated question! And do you have idea like the .map() function works the same way I'm expecting, Thanks

Comment: hey :) when I asked for the snippet i meant more the metadata from the dataarray, not the actual data values

Comment: Also, if you're confused about the `.map` method, try having a look at the xarray docs and see if that helps clear things up :) http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.map.html

Comment: @AWilliams3142 I just have one ques!:

```1) def standardize(x):
  return (x - x.mean())

new_monthly_anomalies = data.groupby('time.month').map(standardize)
```


2)
```data.groupby('time.month') - data.groupby('time.month').mean()
```
Will both of this work the same way?

Comment: I'll have a look into it now :) But still, for future questions it's important to try and have a good layout, so that it's clear what's being asked!

Comment: I think you should be using `data.groupby('time.month') - data.groupby('time.month').mean(dim='time')` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're not specifying what dimensions to take the `.mean()` over. If you specify `.mean(dim='time')` in both of the approaches you've outlined, then you get the same answers, but if you don't specify the `dim` to average over you get different answers.

In future though, please provide some output like this (**for example**) to facilitate answering questions:

```
<xarray.DataArray 't2m' (time: 12, latitude: 721, longitude: 1440)>
[12458880 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 ... 359.25 359.5 359.75
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 90.0 89.75 89.5 89.25 ... -89.5 -89.75 -90.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-01-01 2018-02-01 ... 2018-12-01
Attributes:
    long_name:  2 metre temperature
    units:      K
```

And then when you do operations on your DataArray, try to include output like this ^^ that shows how your operation has affected the metadata/shape etc. Just printing out the values and saying they're correct/not correct doesn't help that much.